# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable using flask-login when calling login_user(user)

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am new to flask and was wondering why I keep getting a TypeError when calling login_user(user) even though a str variable/function was never defined in my code anywhere.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_post():
  user = User()
  username = request.form.get('username')
  password = request.form.get('password')
  if user.get_username != username or user.get_password != password:
    flash('Please check your login details and try again.')
    return redirect(url_for('login')) 
  else:
    login_user(user)
  return redirect(url_for('success'))
```

Here is my models.py:

```
import os
from flask_login import UserMixin


class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self._id = os.getenv("SECRET_ID")
        self._username = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
        self._password = os.getenv("SECRET_PASS")

    @property
    def get_username(self):
        return self._username

    @property
    def get_password(self):
        return self._password

    @property
    def get_id(self):
        return self._id

    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return self.is_active()

    @property
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return True
```

Here is the error message:

```
[2022-05-12 02:48:06,469] ERROR in app: Exception on /login [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "main.py", line 42, in login_post
    login_user(user)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 196, in login_user
    user_id = getattr(user, current_app.login_manager.id_attribute)()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any help to solve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You don't need a ```()``` at the end.

Comment: @ewong That's library code from the `flask_login` module.  The asker didn't write it.

Comment: "get_id" should be a method, not a property. See https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class

Comment: @JohnGordon  my bad.  Misread.  Sorry